# ZMQ hashblock doesn't work

Tags: bitcoind, zeromq, node-services

I'm running a full node,

```
bitcoind .. -zmqpubhashblock=tcp://0.0.0.0:3001 -zmqpubrawtx=tcp://0.0.0.0:3001
```

`rawtx` events work great, but not getting any `hashblock` ones.
Node is **fully synced**, I can see new blocks received in bitcoind output, but it's not announced over zmq.
I consume zmq as fast as possible, so I don't understand why I'm not seeing the `hashblock` events.

Comment: Are you certain that your client is subscribed to receive `hashblock`?

Comment: Maybe the same endpoint is causing conflicts in receiving events? Using separate ports for `hashblock` and `rawtx` events might help.

Comment: No idea why, but adding this solved the problem: -zmqpubrawtxhwm=50000